# is there any way to convert react router to next router with login redirect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js, next-router

I am working on shifting react js to next js, i am facing some issue in react router, supposed i have many dashboard route and those route must be pass though `login` , so i have to pass all the dashboard route though login, if user is not login than redirect to login route.

my react `RouteWithAuthLayout`

```
const RouteWithAuthLayout = props => {
    const { layout: Layout, component: Component, ...rest } = props;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={matchProps => {
                if (!loggedIn()) {
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/auth/login",
                                search: "?next="+window.location.pathname
                            }}
                        />
                    )
                }
                return (
                    <Layout>
                        <Component {...matchProps} />
                    </Layout>
                )
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

and my `Dashboard.js` is look like this

```
<Switch>
  <RouteWithAuthLayout
  component={BuyShipProductDetail}
  layout={DashboardLayout}
  exact
  path="/dashboard/buy-ship-for-me/product/:productNumber/detail"
  />
</Switch>
```

and my `Router.js`

```
<Route path="/dashboard">
  <Dashboard />
</Route>
```

is there any function of class to convert my react router to next router ?

Comment: Nextjs uses filename as the route to the page, so could avoid this route wrapper that u are using. Instead try checking on dashboard page if the user is available through some user context or getServerSideProps. And if there is user then show the dashboard page else redirect to login using router.push() from next/router.

Comment: I'd recommend you have a read through [Migrating from React Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router) and [Authentication](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication) docs.

Comment: can you gave some advice for folder folder structure or how to handle login to redirect using context?